# Bash prompt does not convert escaped characters

Tags: bash, prompt, iterm2

My bash prompt variable in `.profile` looks like this:

```
# $vars
# Always display last 2 directories of current path
current_dir() {
  pwd | awk -F\/ '{print $(NF-1),$(NF)}' | sed 's/ /\//g'
}
# Current git branch
parse_git_branch() {
   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^​*]/d' -e 's/*​ \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

txtblk='\e[0;30m' # Black - Regular
txtred='\e[0;31m' # Red
txtgrn='\e[0;32m' # Green
txtylw='\e[0;33m' # Yellow
txtblu='\e[0;34m' # Blue
txtpur='\e[0;35m' # Purple
txtcyn='\e[0;36m' # Cyan
txtwht='\e[0;37m' # White
bldblk='\e[1;30m' # Black - Bold
bldred='\e[1;31m' # Red
bldgrn='\e[1;32m' # Green
bldylw='\e[1;33m' # Yellow
bldblu='\e[1;34m' # Blue
bldpur='\e[1;35m' # Purple
bldcyn='\e[1;36m' # Cyan
bldwht='\e[1;37m' # White
unkblk='\e[4;30m' # Black - Underline
undred='\e[4;31m' # Red
undgrn='\e[4;32m' # Green
undylw='\e[4;33m' # Yellow
undblu='\e[4;34m' # Blue
undpur='\e[4;35m' # Purple
undcyn='\e[4;36m' # Cyan
undwht='\e[4;37m' # White
bakblk='\e[40m'   # Black - Background
bakred='\e[41m'   # Red
badgrn='\e[42m'   # Green
bakylw='\e[43m'   # Yellow
bakblu='\e[44m'   # Blue
bakpur='\e[45m'   # Purple
bakcyn='\e[46m'   # Cyan
bakwht='\e[47m'   # White
txtrst='\e[0m'    # Text Reset

#           User      Current path (last 2 dirs)    Git branch          Switch to white color
export PS1="$txtcyn\u $txtpur\$(current_dir) $txtgrn\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] \n\$ "
```

So my bash prompt should actually show my username, the current directory the git branch (if there is one) and then a `$` in a new line (just as commented above).
But instead it shows the string literally, without replacing variables or escaped characters like so:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

*Edit:* I use iTerm2 on a Mac

Comment: Did you either take new session or loaded the new .profile as it looked it worked for me.

Comment: Yes. I tried `source ~/.profile`. 
I even declared a test variable on top of the `.profile` file and echoed it after sourcing. That worked. So the file was up-to-date.

Comment: I am using iTerm2 by the way. Maybe this is somewhat relevant.

Comment: Consider installing an up-to-date version of `bash` and using `\W` along with `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` in place of your `current_dir` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create escape sequences inside hard-quotes (`'string'`), they're always interpreted literally.

Use double quotes instead (`"string"`), or try [ansi-c quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (`$'string'`).

You can also simply avoid escaping in the first place, if you choose to stick with hard-quotes.

Comment: This seems to do only half the trick. I replaced all single by double quotes and my bash prompt still looks like this:
`\e[0;36m\u \e[0;35m$(current_dir) \e[0;32m$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] \n$`

If I `echo $PS1` it shows:
 
`$(current_dir) $(parse_git_branch)\[\]
$
\e[0;36m\u \e[0;35m$(current_dir) \e[0;32m$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] \n$`

Comment: you should definitely use the ansi-c quoting then, e.g. `$'\033[9m'`.  to make things easier when formatting output strings, take a look at the [styli.sh formatter](https://github.com/eliranmal/styli.sh). disclaimer: i wrote it